# Is there any plpgsql standard for documenting function interfaces?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm developing a plpgsql function that takes a couple parameters and expect those to follow a specific format. Is there a standard place where I could/should document the function behavior in order to make it user friendly?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach [`COMMENT` strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) to various database objects.

That said, a simple [SQL comment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS) at the top of your function body might stand a better chance of actually being read by future developers.